# django token authentication not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Hi Everyone i have configure token authentication in my project, when i post username and password on postman token are generating but when i added this token to access my api respose then getting
[Authentication credentials were not provided.]

**models.py**

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'api.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        'rest_framework_datatables.renderers.DatatablesRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework_datatables.filters.DatatablesFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework_datatables.pagination.DatatablesPageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100,
}
```

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'api/hisaabApi',views.HisaabViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    path('login',obtain_auth_token,name="login")
]
```

**#api for response**

**views.py**

```
class HisaabViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset=WeeklyData.objects.all()
    serializer_class=HisaabSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class HisaabSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WeeklyData
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Did you pass the token as Bearer?

Comment: from where you are trying to make a post request other than a postman, can u share the relevant code of that part?

Comment: @FaisalNazik i am working on backend only, so i am try on postman, when i post username and password then get token, but when i hit my url  (http://127.0.0.1:8000/fleet/api/hisaabApi/586,2020-11-23,2020-11-29/) to get response my api also add token on header in postman then got [ "Authentication credentials were not provided."]

Answer (score 1):

Butterfly

if you are using post man you should not insert the token in **params** section, thats why when you are entering the Bearer and the token, it will be typed in the url at the top.
[image]

what you should do is to enter the Bearer and the token in **headers** part in `postman` , then your code will work just fine.

[image]